# How to solve an LMI feasibility problem with such an equality constraints?

Tags: matlab

My friend is now researching on a simulation problem in control theory with MATLAB, where a linear matrix inequality (LMI) feasiblity problem needs to be solved at first. However, in this LMI problem, there is an equality constraint shown as following
[image: equality constraints]

we have no idea how to express this condition with lmi solver in MATLAB, and can't find any instructions on Internet. Anyone can help us out? Thanks.